# Possible ranks of matrix if $\operatorname{rank}(AB)$ = $\operatorname{rank}(BA)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

If matrix $A \in M_n(R)$ is defined such as for each $B \in M_n(R)$ we have $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = \operatorname{rank}(BA)$ find all possible ranks of $A$.

So obviously, $I$ and $0$ are both one of the possibilities for $A$. As it [turns out](https://www.quora.com/If-A-is-invertible-how-can-I-show-that-rank-AB-rank-B-rank-BA), for each invertible matrix $A$ this equation is true. So we know that $n$ and $0$ are two possibilities of $\operatorname{rank}(A)$.

But what about other ranks? I personally think that this equality is only true if $\operatorname{rank}(A)$ is either $0$ or $n$. But I've got no way to prove it. I tried to struggle with nullspace of $A$ and create a $B$ with it in which $AB = 0$ but $BA \neq 0$ but I could not prove that this matrix always exists.

Comment: Can you expand on your last sentence?  Suppose $0 \lt \dim \ker A \lt n$. Then there is some $\mathbf v$ such that $\mathbf v^TA\neq \mathbf 0^T$ and some $\mathbf x \neq 0$ such that $A\mathbf x =0$ so set $B:=\mathbf {xv}^T$

Comment: @user8675309 Thanks! That looks like a neat approach!